# Year Only in ExtJs, overriding css of extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I need a date picker which let me choose 'year' only in extjs.I already have multiple datepicker in my application, but for this i need to choose year only. Is there any way i can override css of datepicker(Extjs have component which shows month and year but not year only). I don't want to define custom component, i want to use datepicker by overriding it's css. I found one custom css example over stackoverflow.Please check it out here.

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define('Ext.ux.OnlyYearPicker', {
        xtype: 'onlyyearpicker',
        extend: 'Ext.picker.Month',

        afterRender: function(){
            this.callParent();
            this.el.setStyle({width: '106px',})
        },

        renderTpl: [
        '<div id="{id}-bodyEl" data-ref="bodyEl" class="{baseCls}-body">',
          '<div style="display: none; width:0px;" id="{id}-monthEl" data-ref="monthEl" class="{baseCls}-months">',
              '<tpl for="months">',
                  '<div class="{parent.baseCls}-item {parent.baseCls}-month">',
                      '<a style="{parent.monthStyle}" role="button" hidefocus="on" class="{parent.baseCls}-item-inner">{.}</a>',
                  '</div>',
              '</tpl>',
          '</div>',
          '<div id="{id}-yearEl" data-ref="yearEl" class="{baseCls}-years">',
              '<div class="{baseCls}-yearnav">',
                  '<div class="{baseCls}-yearnav-button-ct">',
                      '<a id="{id}-prevEl" data-ref="prevEl" class="{baseCls}-yearnav-button {baseCls}-yearnav-prev" hidefocus="on" role="button"></a>',
                  '</div>',
                  '<div class="{baseCls}-yearnav-button-ct">',
                      '<a id="{id}-nextEl" data-ref="nextEl" class="{baseCls}-yearnav-button {baseCls}-yearnav-next" hidefocus="on" role="button"></a>',
                  '</div>',
              '</div>',
              '<tpl for="years">',
                  '<div class="{parent.baseCls}-item {parent.baseCls}-year">',
                      '<a hidefocus="on" class="{parent.baseCls}-item-inner" role="button">{.}</a>',
                  '</div>',
              '</tpl>',
          '</div>',
          '<div class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'clear"></div>',
          '<tpl if="showButtons">',
              '<div class="{baseCls}-buttons">{%',
                  'var me=values.$comp, okBtn=me.okBtn, cancelBtn=me.cancelBtn;',
                  'okBtn.ownerLayout = cancelBtn.ownerLayout = me.componentLayout;',
                  'okBtn.ownerCt = cancelBtn.ownerCt = me;',
                  'Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup(okBtn.getRenderTree(), out);',
                  'Ext.DomHelper.generateMarkup(cancelBtn.getRenderTree(), out);',
              '%}</div>',
          '</tpl>',
        '</div>'
    ]
    });


    Ext.define('Ext.form.field.Month', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.field.Date',
        alias: 'widget.monthfield',
        requires: ['Ext.picker.Month', 'Ext.ux.OnlyYearPicker'],
        alternateClassName: ['Ext.form.MonthField', 'Ext.form.Month'],
        selectMonth: null,
        createPicker: function() {
            var me = this,
                format = Ext.String.format;
            return Ext.create('Ext.ux.OnlyYearPicker', {
                pickerField: me,
                ownerCt: me.ownerCt,
                renderTo: document.body,
                floating: true,
                hidden: true,
                focusOnShow: true,
                minDate: me.minValue,
                maxDate: me.maxValue,
                disabledDatesRE: me.disabledDatesRE,
                disabledDatesText: me.disabledDatesText,
                disabledDays: me.disabledDays,
                disabledDaysText: me.disabledDaysText,
                format: me.format,
                showToday: me.showToday,
                startDay: me.startDay,
                minText: format(me.minText, me.formatDate(me.minValue)),
                maxText: format(me.maxText, me.formatDate(me.maxValue)),
                listeners: {
                    select: {
                        scope: me,
                        fn: me.onSelect
                    },
                    monthdblclick: {
                        scope: me,
                        fn: me.onOKClick
                    },
                    yeardblclick: {
                        scope: me,
                        fn: me.onOKClick
                    },
                    OkClick: {
                        scope: me,
                        fn: me.onOKClick
                    },
                    CancelClick: {
                        scope: me,
                        fn: me.onCancelClick
                    }
                },
                keyNavConfig: {
                    esc: function() {
                        me.collapse();
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        onCancelClick: function() {
            var me = this;
            me.selectMonth = null;
            me.collapse();
        },
        onOKClick: function() {
            var me = this;
            if (me.selectMonth) {
                me.setValue(me.selectMonth);
                me.fireEvent('select', me, me.selectMonth);
            }
            me.collapse();
        },
        onSelect: function(m, d) {
            var me = this;
            me.selectMonth = new Date((d[0] + 1) + '/1/' + d[1]);
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Month', {
        format: 'Y',
        fieldLabel: 'Date',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you have any reason why the year cannot be picked through a `numberfield`?

Comment: thanks for help but client's Need. He want me to add through datepicker, to maintain the look and feel of the page and for the ease in maintain future enhancement of the module.

Comment: Sorry, but "for the ease in maintain future enhancement" completely contradicts the amount of specialty code you already have. "Maintain the look and feel" is a valid argument.

Comment: I am using jquery now. It's much more easy to customize it. Thanks for the help alexander. I appreciate that! :)